# Trying to right click a preference pane in System Preferences with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to automate right clicking on a system pane as part of a deployment with applescript (then ultimately remove it...I do not want to do this directly by deleting the preference pane from Finder as it seems to cause other issues)

The preference pane button is called "TX NTFS" so I set the code to

tell application "System Events" to tell button "TX NTFS" to perform action "AXShowMenu"

which should bring up the right click, but instead gives me the error "Can't get button \"TX NTFS"\ even though thats what its accessibility title is in Accessibility inspector.

Any ideas, can't find anything relating to right click (or rather removing preference panes in via AppleScript)

Comment: Many times (not always !) the right click can be provided by click with option key or command key or both. if thesis your cases, then use the "click using {command down}" or click {using command down, option down}

Comment: Hi @pbell in this case CTRL and click works,would that be `tell application "System Events" to click button "TX NTFS" using CTRL down` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "your_process"
    tell front window
        key down {command}
        click button "your_button"
        delay 1
        key up {command}
    end tell

end tell
end tell
```